# Volumetric lighting not working when building and running game

Tags: unity, lighting, build-process, export

I have a volumetric lighting system implemented into Unity and when I am making the game and run it in the Unity editor the volumetric lighting shows up. When I build it and run it though it doesn't.

I think this is caused because it has not exported the script with the volumetric lighting so I exported it again and it still didn't show. I dont know what is up. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

In Unity with the thing working:

[image: Working effect]

Unity built game:

[image: No volumetric lighting in build]

Comment: For what platform did you build the game?

Comment: unity... I thought this thread was just unity but i guess not

Comment: What I meant with "what platform" was what target you clicked on when you exported your Unity game. Windows? Linux? iOS? Android? WebGL?

Comment: You should also show us your rendering/quality settings for that platform, which can affect what visual effects are supported.

Comment: all the unity lighting settings are default. The volumetric lighting script is attatched to the camera and a different one to the light to add that fog effect. It is all scripted and I do not believe any settings will effect it. But. The quality settings are both ultra.Texture quality is full res anistropic textures is forced on. Shadows all default and other all default. If you want more detail for certain settings i can show you.

Comment: @Titaniumammas69 Are you building for Windows, Linux, OSX, WebGL, Android, iOS, Nintendo Switch, XBox, Playstation, or what?

Comment: Its windows fyi

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. After reading these over I realised my mistake of being difficult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built the game with console and looked for errors. It said a 3 shaders were missing and told me to make sure it is included in "always include shaders" in ProjectSettings/Graphics. So I changed the size from 8 to 11 and added the 3 shaders and "voilà," which in french means and then I found out. Now my game looks much better!